# Being unable to update Cookie using php

Tags: php, cookies

I am using a cookie to save a PHP array(0 => 0, 1=>0,......,99=>0) and I encode the array into JSON in order to be able to save it in the cookie, the problem is that when I decode the JSON to retrieve the array and change the value of a field I am unable to update the cookie and I dont really know why.

This is the code I use to create the cookie:

```
$carrito=array(0=>0);
            $sql = "SELECT ID FROM productos";
            $ids = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($ids->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $ids->fetch_assoc()) {
                    array_push($carrito, 0);
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();//cerramos la conexión
            setcookie("carrito", json_encode($carrito), time()+(86400),"/");
```

And this is the code I use to decode the JSON and go throught the arrat to modify it:

```
 if(isset($_POST["id"])){
            $idProducto=$_POST["id"];
            $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE["carrito"]),true);
            print_r($data);
            echo "</br>".$idProducto."</br>";
            foreach($data as $id => $cantidad){
                if($id == $idProducto){
                    $cantidad++;
                }
            }
            print_r($data);
            setcookie("carrito", json_encode($data), time()+(86400),"/");
        }
```

The problem is that after decoding the json when I try to go throught the array it doesnt recognize the line $data as $id => $cantidad.

This is what I get when I print_r($data):

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this by using:

```
$data[$idProducto]++;
```

instead of the foreach loop